# Unable to deserialize or get the values into my object from service

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, rest

How to deserialize this below result from service to my object? I want only the Name, City and State values. I tried to use

```
{{
  "id": "123",
  "name": "Kaizen",
  "living": {
    "city": "Sydney",
    "state": "NSW"
  },
  "Country": {
    "name": "Australia",
    "region": "APAC"
  }
}}

JavaScriptSerializer details= new JavaScriptSerializer();
                var detailsOfDoc= service.Deserialize<DoctorDetails>(docDetails.ToString());


My DoctorDetails Class is as follows

public class DoctorDetails
{
 public string Name { get; set;}
public string State{ get; set;}
public string City{ get; set;}
}
```

I see the values as null in detailsOfDoc variable.

**EDIT**

The below response is what I get in the endpoint when I hit in browser for an ID

```
<DoctorDetails xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="Northshore.Details">
<Id>111</Id>
<Name>Kaizen</Name>
<Living>
<City>Sydney</City>
<State>NSW</State>
</Living>
<Country>
<Name>Australia</Name>
<Region>APAC</Region>
</Country>
</DoctorDetails>
```

Comment: What kind of object are you receiving?... It's not valid JSON

Comment: @MarkC.: Jesus mate, I get that after doing some conversion myself lol.

Comment: Haha no wonder it isn't working. Can you get it into valid JSON?

Comment: @MarkC.: I do this var docDetails= _clientService.GetAsync<object>(getRequest).Result;

Comment: Do you have access to that endpoint? Or maybe you could parse the result and strip off the leading and traing `{}`

Comment: Yes, I do have access to end point. Let me paste what I see that

Comment: @MarkC.: That is what I see when I hit the endpoint in browser (Editted my response in question)

Comment: Well that's XML, and it looks like valid XML..I'm wondering what's going on there. instead of `object` can you put `DoctorDetails` and see what happens?

Comment: @MarkC.: Thank you, you are right, I used DoctorDetails and I was afraid to see null damn

Comment: Does it work and deserialize OK?

Comment: @MarkC.: I see the docDetails with 3 properties as I expect, but all have null values if I use DoctorDetails instead of object lol. Whats going on :D I am new to development ;)

Comment: Take `ToString()` off of `docDetails` - see what happens

Comment: @MarkC.: I am saying the docDetails itself is with properties that are null.

Comment: @MarkC.: I mean this is null var docDetails= _clientService.GetAsync<DoctorDetails>(getRequest).Result; unless if I use "object" instead of "DoctorDetails" in the type

Comment: ok, throw object back in there. Is any other code calling that same end points?

Comment: Deserialize the xml to object !

Comment: @MarkC.: No, it is only new functionality I am calling this service.